MAUI: Compatibility.Layout<T> doesn't display anything
I struggle with Xamarin -> MAUI conversion and stuck with the issue in Compatibility.Layout<T>, it doesn't display anything.
The MAUI project based on .NET 8.0 and Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility 8.0.21
I expect to see a label (the same code works on xamarin forms).
MAUI android lacks of the text label 
MAUI winui3 throw an exception

Xamarin forms android works fine
Xamarin forms uwp works fine

Maui and Xamarin code and screenshots are below.
What am I missing?
Here is my MAUI code (which doesn't work):
My custom layout control:
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility;

namespace MauiApp2
{
    public class CustomVerticalStackLayout : Layout<View>
    {
        private readonly Label lbl;

        public CustomVerticalStackLayout()
        {
            lbl = new Label { Text = "test", FontSize = 20, BackgroundColor = Colors.Red, HeightRequest = 100, WidthRequest = 100, Margin = 20 };

            Children.Add(lbl);

            BackgroundColor = Colors.Blue;
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            return new Size(200, 200);
        }

        protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(lbl, new Rect(0, 0, 150, 150));
        }
    }

    public class CustomControl : ContentView
    {
        public CustomControl()
        {
            this.BackgroundColor = Colors.Green;

            this.Padding = new Thickness(30);
            this.Content = new CustomVerticalStackLayout();
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            return new Size(230, 230);
        }
    }
}

XAML:
<ContentPage xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui
             xmlns:x=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml
             x:Class="MauiApp2.MainPage"
             xmlns:c="clr-namespace:MauiApp2"
             BackgroundColor="Yellow"
             Padding="20">

    <c:CustomControl/>

</ContentPage>

MauiProgram:
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .UseMauiCompatibility()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

Android result: no text label

Windows result: Throw an excpetion
The handler's MauiContext cannot be null.

XAMARIN FORMS EXAMPLE
The very same code on the Xamarin Forms works fine.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Xam
{
    public class CustomVerticalStackLayout : Layout<View>
    {
        private readonly Label lbl;

        public CustomVerticalStackLayout()
        {
            lbl = new Label { Text = "test", FontSize = 20, BackgroundColor = Color.Red, HeightRequest = 100, WidthRequest = 100, Margin = 20 };

            Children.Add(lbl);

            BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        }

        protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            return new SizeRequest(new Size(200, 200));
        }

        protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(lbl, new Rect(0, 0, 150, 150));
        }
    }

    public class CustomControl : ContentView
    {
        public CustomControl()
        {
            this.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;

            this.Padding = new Thickness(30);
            this.Content = new CustomVerticalStackLayout();
        }

        protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            return new SizeRequest(new Size(230, 230));
        }
    }
}

I expected to see this. This is screenshots from the same code but on Xamarin Forms.


I did a test using the code you shared above, but there is nothing displayed on my android emulator on Maui.  Is your code uploaded correctly?

thank you, yes the code is the correct one, what do you mean by nothing displayed? yes, it's nothing - no label, that I expected to see, only backgrouds...

If I understand correctly, according to your screenshot above, in Maui, on the Android platform, the control is displayed normally, but on Windows, the control is not displayed, right?

no, the last screenshot are xamarin version which works and it is expected; on maui version there is no text label in red box on android and winui3 throws an exception.

Yes, it is just the case as you said. For this problem, you can create a new issue here. Thanks for your support and feedback for Maui. :)

I have found you have created a new issue in Github of Maui about this problem. As a summary, I will post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems. :)

Yes, it is just the case as this thread mentioned.
And there is a known issue about this: MAUI: Compatibility.Layout doesn't display anything without child.Measure posted by Pavlo Datsiuk.
But as a workaround mentioned by the issue above, we can try to add code  lbl.Measure(0,0); before adding the new control.
public CustomVerticalStackLayout()
        {
            lbl = new Label { Text = "test", FontSize = 20, BackgroundColor = Colors.Red, HeightRequest = 100, WidthRequest = 100, Margin = 20 };

            //as a workaround, we can add the following code
            lbl.Measure(0,0);

            Children.Add(lbl);

            BackgroundColor = Colors.Blue;
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            return new Size(200, 200);
        }

        protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(lbl, new Rect(0, 0, 150, 150));
        }
    }

